# Checking if pointer is NULL gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, null

The problem statement: We have to delete every alternate node of a Linked List. 
Eg: Original list: 1->2->3->4->5 to: 1->3->5

complete problem statement: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/delete-alternate-nodes/1/?ref=self

As you can see, this is a function problem so I'm not actually writing the complete code(just have to complete the function). Here is the code that I'm writing:

```
void deleteAlt(struct Node *head){
    // Code here
    struct Node *traverse=head,*alternate=head->next;

    if(alternate->next==NULL)
    {
        head->next=NULL;
        return;
    }

    while(traverse->next!=NULL && alternate->next!=NULL)
    {
        traverse->next = alternate->next;
        traverse = traverse->next;
        alternate = traverse->next;
        if((alternate->next)==NULL) //presence of this if statement causes segmentation fault
        {
            traverse->next=NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

I have gone through similar problems on stackoverflow but their code and objective were different, like, not initializing the pointer and comparing it. However, my problem is different.

In the case when number of nodes is even, `alternate` is always going to be NULL and hence there should be no initialization problem.

Comment: what if there're only one node?

Comment: @songziming in that case traverse->next will be NULL and nothing happens(because it does not enter the while loop). Which is the expected behavior.

Comment: `traverse->next` will be `NULL`, which means `alternative` will be `NULL`. Now you see the problem?

Comment: @TotallyNoob look at my answer, I did transformations step by step from your code to show the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you do

```
while(traverse->next!=NULL && alternate->next!=NULL)
  traverse->next = alternate->next;
  traverse = traverse->next;
  alternate = traverse->next;
  if((alternate->next)==NULL) //presence of this if statement causes segmentation fault
```

so in fact

```
while(traverse->next!=NULL && alternate->next!=NULL)
  traverse = alternate->next;
  alternate = traverse->next;
  if((alternate->next)==NULL) //presence of this if statement causes segmentation fault
```

so in fact

```
while(traverse->next!=NULL && alternate->next!=NULL)
  alternate = alternate->next->next;
  if((alternate->next)==NULL) //presence of this if statement causes segmentation fault
```

so in fact

```
while(traverse->next!=NULL && alternate->next!=NULL)
  if((alternate->next->next->next)==NULL) //presence of this if statement causes segmentation fault
```

when `alternate->next->next` is NULL (not checked by the *while*) `alternate->next->next->next` causes your segmentation fault

---

A solution is :

```
void deleteAlt(struct Node * head)
{
  if (head != NULL) {
    while (head->next != NULL) {
      Node * d = head->next;

      head->next = head->next->next;
      free(d);
      head = head->next;
    }
  }
}
```

A complete program to prove :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
  int v;
  struct Node * next;
} Node;

Node * make(int v, Node * n)
{
  Node * r = malloc(sizeof(Node));

  r->v = v;
  r->next = n;

  return r;
}

void pr(Node * l)
{
  while (l != NULL) {
    printf("%d ", l->v);
    l = l->next;
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

void deleteAlt(struct Node * head)
{
  if (head != NULL) {
    while (head->next != NULL) {
      Node * d = head->next;

      head->next = head->next->next;
      free(d);
      head = head->next;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  Node * l = make(1, make(2, make(3, make(4, make(5, NULL)))));

  pr(l);
  deleteAlt(l);
  pr(l);

  /* free rest of list */
  while (l != NULL) {
    Node * n = l->next;

    free(l);
    l = n;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantc -Wextra l.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 2 3 4 5 
1 3 5 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind* to check memory accesses/leaks

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==2479== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2479== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2479== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2479== Command: ./a.out
==2479== 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 3 5 
==2479== 
==2479== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2479==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2479==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 1,064 bytes allocated
==2479== 
==2479== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2479== 
==2479== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2479== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

---

(edit) In case the length of the list can be even the definition must be changed to :

```
void deleteAlt(struct Node * head)
{
  while ((head != NULL) && (head->next != NULL)) {
    Node * d = head->next;

    head->next = head->next->next;
    free(d);
    head = head->next;
  }
}
```

modifying *main* to check :

```
int main()
{
  {
    Node * l = make(1, make(2, make(3, make(4, make(5, NULL)))));

    pr(l);
    deleteAlt(l);
    pr(l);

    /* free rest of list */
    while (l != NULL) {
      Node * n = l->next;

      free(l);
      l = n;
    }
  }
  {
    Node * l = make(1, make(2, make(3, make(4, NULL))));

    pr(l);
    deleteAlt(l);
    pr(l);

    /* free rest of list */
    while (l != NULL) {
      Node * n = l->next;

      free(l);
      l = n;
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra l.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 2 3 4 5 
1 3 5 
1 2 3 4 
1 3
```

and under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==3450== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3450== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3450== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3450== Command: ./a.out
==3450== 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 3 5 
1 2 3 4 
1 3 
==3450== 
==3450== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3450==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3450==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 1,096 bytes allocated
==3450== 
==3450== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3450== 
==3450== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3450== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I kind of get what my mistake is but how can I resolve it? In case of even number of nodes I have to drop the last node which needs this condition evaluation.

Comment: @TotallyNoob I edited my answer to put a solution, including a full program to execute it and show it works

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the help but it still gives segmentation fault. I feel that this might be problem at their backend since the code works perfectly under _valgrind_

Comment: @TotallyNoob may be they also do test with a partial list having an even length ? I edited my answer to also manage that case

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
void deleteAlt(struct Node *head){

    struct Node * head_tmp=head;
    struct Node * tmp=NULL;

    while(head_tmp->next!=NULL){

        tmp=head_tmp->next;

        head_tmp->next=tmp->next;

        head_tmp=tmp->next;

        //do something for freeing tmp node 

    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can see a code smell in

```
if(alternate->next==NULL)
    {
        head->next=NULL;
        return;
    }
```

What if i have a single node? In that case `alternate` points to null.

Comment: In that case traverse->next will be NULL and nothing happens(because it does not enter the while loop). Which is the expected behavior.

Comment: What if alternate is NULL? If alternate is NULL then in if condition, its NULL -> next . Hence segmentation fault

Comment: You are talking about first if statement and I corrected that. Still segmentation fault. In the case of while loop it won't enter it.